# PostGIS: Count number of vertices of lines and polygons in tables

Tags: postgis

I have 23 tables in a PostGIS schema which I need to count the number of vertices of. The tables are a mixture of lines and polygons so realised I need to use ST_NPoints(geom)

So I ran the following query

```
SELECT count(ST_NPoints(geom) FROM lines;
```

the result/count equals the number of features in that table and not the total number of vertices of all features in that table.

I must be missing something but cannot figure it out (must be monday morning ;))

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With your query you are only counting the number of rows in your table (see it, as the number of times that you are calling st_npoints), you need to **sum** the results that returns st_npoints for each geometry

```
SELECT sum(ST_NPoints(geom)) FROM lines;
```

Comment: many thanks that works perfectly. I knew it must be simple